# How should I implement this pattern of calling asynchronously in a loop without C#'s async?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await

I'm trying to implement this trivial task of listing all objects in an AmazonS3 bucket with paged requests asynchronously in C#4. I have it working in C#5 using the following snippet:

```
var listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().WithBucketName(bucketName);
ListObjectsResponse listResponse = null;
var list = new List<List<S3Object>>();

while (listResponse == null || listResponse.IsTruncated)
{
    listResponse = await Task<ListObjectsResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        client.BeginListObjects, client.EndListObjects, listRequest, null);

    list.Add(listResponse.S3Objects);

    if (listResponse.IsTruncated)
    {
        listRequest.Marker = listResponse.NextMarker;
    }
}

return list.SelectMany(l => l);
```

I'm calling the BeginListObjects/EndListObjects pair asynchronously, but I have to repeat that call every time the response says it's truncated. This piece of code works for me.

However, I now want to do this in C#4's TPL, where I don't have the luxury of using async/await and want to understand if this can be done using continuations.

How do I do this same thing in C#4?

Comment: Not sure if its what you are wanting, but you can still use Async/Await in C# 4.0. Grab the Async Targeting Pack off of Nuget - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack

Comment: @Tallek That package is designed just for experimental testing; it's not a production worthy package that should be used for "real" applications.

Comment: @Servy Interesting, I hadn't known. I know the original AsyncCTP was not for production, but I was under the assumption the targeting pack was production worthy. Any documentation you can link to stating otherwise?

Comment: @Tallek I was under the impression that that was the AsyncCTP.

Comment: @Servy I don't think so... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/04/24/async-targeting-pack.aspx

Comment: The Async Targeting Pack is created specifically to allow the async language feature to be used with .NET 4.0 projects, but requires C#5/VS2012. I'm specifically using C#4/VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so rather than putting the items into a list with each task/continuation it's easier in a non-await model to just have each task/continuation return the entire sequence.  Given that, I used the following helper method to add each one's iterative results onto the aggregate total.

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> Concat<T>(Task<IEnumerable<T>> first
        , Task<IEnumerable<T>> second)
{
    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { first, second }, _ =>
    {
        return first.Result.Concat(second.Result);
    });
}
```

Next, I used the follow method to take a task of a single result and turn it into a task of a sequence (containing just that one item).

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> ToSequence<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<T>>();
    task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        else if (task.IsFaulted)
            tcs.SetException(task.Exception);
        else
            tcs.SetResult(Enumerable.Repeat(task.Result, 1));
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Note here that you have some fields/locals not defined; I'm assuming you can add them to the appropriate method without difficulty.

```
private Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>> method(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ListObjectsResponse listResponse = null;
    return Task<ListObjectsResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        client.BeginListObjects, client.EndListObjects, listRequest, null)
        .ToSequence()
        .ContinueWith(continuation);
}
```

Here is where the real magic happens.  Basically,

```
public Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>> continuation(Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>> task)
{
    if (task.Result == null)  //not quite sure what null means here//may need to edit this recursive case
    {
        return Task<ListObjectsResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                client.BeginListObjects, client.EndListObjects, listRequest, null)
                .ToSequence()
                .ContinueWith(continuation);
    }
    else if (task.Result.First().IsTruncated)
    {
        //if the results were trunctated then concat those results with 
        //TODO modify the request marker here; either create a new one or store the request as a field and mutate.
        Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>> nextBatch = Task<ListObjectsResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                client.BeginListObjects, client.EndListObjects, listRequest, null)
                .ToSequence()
                .ContinueWith(continuation);
        return Concat(nextBatch, task);//recursive continuation call
    }
    else //if we're done it means the existing results are sufficient
    {
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, although it's O(n^2), where n is the number of pages, because of the way you're concatenating the results. But if you have so many pages that this is a problem, you probably don't want use a simple `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` either.

Comment: Actually, I think Servy is right. The concatenation is deferred, so a call to Concatenate() doesn't actually do much except chain the result of one iteration to all the previous iterations. This is very much the same effect as keeping the returned lists in a list, except you don't use a list. There's no copying happening while iterating.

Comment: @svick I thought it would just be O(n), given the way execution is deferred, but even if it's not, the effort spent concatenating the results will be completely dwarfed by the multiple network connections.  Given how small of a percentage of the time is spent on that action optimizing it shouldn't be of high priority.

Comment: I can't get it to work. There's multiple issues that I can identify, but when trying to solve it myself, I'm just running in circles. 1- continuation doesn't take a Task<ListObjectsResponse>, so there's no task.Result.IsTruncated, 2- ContinueWith(continuation) doesn't return a Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>> but a Task<Task<IEnumerable<S3Object>>.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde Yeah, that stems from all of the types/variables you have defined that I didn't, so I couldn't really use the compiler much to help me out.  I've edited the post; it's not a big conceptual difference, but it should compile now.  Oh, and I fixed a bug with `Concat` in which it didn't verify they both were finished.